# Call async function in setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to use d3 slider with react so to throttle redux action.

I use below code

```
export const changeNumber = (number) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // Clear old timeId
  if (getState().time.timeId !== null) {  
    clearTimeout(getState().time.timeId);
  }
  // Create new timeId
  const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
    
    dispatch(debounceChangeNumber(number));
  }, 1000);
  // refresh to new timeId
  dispatch(updateTimeId(timeId));
  
};

export const debounceChangeNumber = (number) => {
  return {
    type: "CHANGE_NUMBER",
    payload: number,
  };
};

// Throttle redux call, refresh to new timeId
export const updateTimeId = (timeId) => {
  return {
    type: "UPDATE_TIME_ID",
    payload: timeId,
  };
};
```

It kind of hard to use same `timeId` with multi actions, if i use same `timeId` how should inside actions be async ? Like

```
const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
    // These actions should be asynchronous
    dispatch(debounceChangeNumber(number));
    dispacth(funcA());
    dispacth(funcB());
    ....
  }, 5000);
```

I really want to know which  is best approach for this kind of thing, because if I use this in bigger application I have to create new `timeId` state for each components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather complicated to do this yourself, but good for learning.

To get forwards use a debounce function from the library you are already using (e.g. _.debounce) or get a useDebounce hook (https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce)

If you want to do this for learning purposes, this is a good tutorial to follow: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function